# Multiple NFS share from a single client

Tags: nfs

is it possible to export more than one nfs share for a single client?
in my /etc/export i have:

```
 /share/dir1  client1_hostname*(rw,fsid=0,sync,no_root_squash)
 /share/dir2  client1_hostname*(rw,fsid=0,sync,no_root_squash)
```

on the client side when i mount the directries

```
 mount -t  nfs server_ip:/share/dir1 /client/dir1
 mount -t  nfs server_ip:/share/dir2 /client/dir2
```

the mount is successfuly, but both mounts end up looking at the first exported directory from the server.

is what i am trying to do possible?

Regards and thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method is valid but I believe the issue is that you've got `fsid=0` set on both. You do not need to set `fsid`. Remove it, and rexport with `exportfs -r -a`